# How do I launch a URL in browser from an OnClick event on a TextView?

Tags: android, url, textview, launch

I have read the answer "How do I launch a URL in the browser from my Application on Android" but I am still confused.

------>
Basically I have a TextView that will be displaying different names of famous people, and what I want is, to perform a google search in the browser that searches for the text that is currently displayed in the TextView, when the user clicks on the TextView itself.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it has something to do with android:autoLink="web" but I need it to go to url ("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + textviewtext). I also need it to convert spaces to %20 or whatever so that it searches properly. Maybe there is a simpler way? Like having it perform the default search method? Is there such a thing as android:autolink="search" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in onClickListner event write this code:

```
String url = textView.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think that will work, and as soon as I can test and confirm I will click the green check, but there is one error preventing me from testing, in the line 'source = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sourcetv);'    the R is underscored as an error, so then I click to import android.R, but then the underscore goes to 'sourcetv' and says 'sourcetv cannot be resolved or is not a field' but I have the line 'android:id="@+id/sourcetv"' in my main.xml for that textview.

Comment: No DO NOT add android.R, there must be some mistake in your XML. Try to look at your xml first or Clean your project. Project>clean Project from the menu. If the problem persists paste your xml code here.

Comment: I looked hard and can't find anything wrong. Here is the relevant part:
<(linear layout)
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quotetv"
        android:layout_height="300px" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/quotetv"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/sourcetv"
        android:text="@string/sourcetv"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
    
        />

Comment: If it helps, the R is underscored in the line 'setContentView(R.layout.main);' too

Comment: Ok I just did another clean, this time with "Start build immediately" and it fixed it. I will test shortly and check the box, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: paste the parent layout properties...(i.e. main linear layout)

Comment: One headache after another with Android. :( I now have no errors in any files in my entire project, but there is the red error X on the project folder itself. When I try to run, it says 'Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1' and above that gives some lengthy explanation about using core libraries like java. but im not importing any java.anything     Do you have any idea what error this is?

Comment: do one thing.
open project properties>android tab> uncheck android version>then check it again. and in libraries remove all libraries other then android and then again clean the project

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I understand is that you want to launch Google search for the text when you click on the TextView. Here is a code to directly launch Google search of the text provided:

```
String searchKey = "Text From your TextView";
Intent search = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);  
search.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, searchKey);  
startActivity(search);
```

Comment: Thanks I used a combination of both of these answers, but I still have this Dalvik error so I can't test it yet.